# What is the meaning of these Flutter errors?

Tags: flutter, dart

It receives information as a web socket from an esp32 operating as Access Point. I have an interface through which I process the received information. I keep and process information with getx. While debugging the application, it pauses and when you advance it, it gives a lot of errors, but the application works 90%.

```
E/flutter (17169): #32     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
E/flutter (17169): #33     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
E/flutter (17169): #34     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2447:41)
E/flutter (17169): #35     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1594:10)
E/flutter (17169): #36     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (17169): #37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (17169): #38     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784:19)
E/flutter (17169): #39     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658:7)
E/flutter (17169): #40     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606:5)
E/flutter (17169): #41     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1936:33)
E/flutter (17169): #42     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1379:14)
E/flutter (17169): #43     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (17169): #44     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (17169):
```

EDİTED:
The debugger stops in between and gives the following 5 errors via the cal stack.

```
Main isolate is paused in the debugger

****
Error._throw (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:27)
Error.throwWithStackTrace (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\errors.dart:120)
_rootHandleError.<anonymous closure> (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\zone.dart:1386)
_microtaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:40)
_startMicrotaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:49)
***
Error._throw (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:27)
Error.throwWithStackTrace (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\errors.dart:120)
_rootHandleError.<anonymous closure> (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\zone.dart:1386)
_microtaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:40)
_startMicrotaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:49)
***
Error._throw (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:27)
Error.throwWithStackTrace (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\errors.dart:120)
_rootHandleError.<anonymous closure> (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\zone.dart:1386)
_microtaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:40)
_startMicrotaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:49)
***
Error._throw (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:27)
Error.throwWithStackTrace (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\errors.dart:120)
_rootHandleError.<anonymous closure> (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\zone.dart:1386)
_microtaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:40)
_startMicrotaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:49)
***
Error._throw (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:27)
Error.throwWithStackTrace (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\core\errors.dart:120)
_rootHandleError.<anonymous closure> (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\zone.dart:1386)
_microtaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:40)
_startMicrotaskLoop (c:\src\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\async\schedule_microtask.dart:49)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that the esp32 data is not received to the application. And closing any streams or any other controllers may solve this. The data sent and received are depends on how it is streamed, esp32 may not able to handle the stream request from the application

Comment: The incoming data was not processed properly. I changed a code snippet and there were variables that remained unanswered in the subsequent codes.